# CSS: How to shorter code having select direct children with multiple id

Tags: css

I have this:

```css
#cbfr_196 > .my_field {width: 95%;}
```

Now I have more ID to include so I could make this:

```css
#cbfr_196 > .my_field {width: 95%;}
#cbfr_197 > .my_field {width: 95%;}
#cbfr_198 > .my_field {width: 95%;}
```

but I would like shorten the code. I made some test but I don't see how to do.

If I do this:

```css
#cbfr_196, #cbfr_197, #cbfr_198 > .my_field {width: 95%;}
```

this work only for ID #cbfr_198 and if I remove comma, nothing work.

any clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
[id^="cbfr"] > .my_field {width: 95%;}
```

That says—"target any `.my_field` that's the child of an element whose ID starts with `cbfr`".

As an aside, your one-line attempt didn't work because each part between the commas is a complete rule. For it to work, it would have to look like this:

```
#cbfr_196 > .my_field, #cbfr_197 > .my_field, #cbfr_198 > .my_field {width: 95%;}
```

But that's not much of an improvement, of course.

Comment: Your first suggestion will not work in my case because a majority of my "cbfr" ID do not need any change. Is only some dozen of ID which need a modification. Your second suggestion seem to be my best bet if no others solutions can work. Thank for your clarification about my one-line test.

Comment: None of these rules target the `cbfr` elements. They are targeting the `.my_field` element inside them. So if there's no `.my_field` element, the rule doesn't apply.

Comment: That the problem...in each of my ID I have .my_field

Comment: In that case, you'd have to find some kind of pattern in the ones you do want to style if you want to do anything other than that longer line I showed.